# How do I diff only certain files?

Tags: diff, patch

I have a list of files (a subset of the files in a directory) and I want to generate a patch that includes only the differences in those files.

From the diff manual, it looks like I can exclude (-x), but would need to specify that for every file that I don't want to include, which seems cumbersome and difficult to script cleanly.

Is there a way to just give diff a list of files? I've already isolated the files with the changes into a separate directory, and I also have a file with the list of filenames, so I can present it to diff in whichever way works best.

What I've tried:

```
cd filestodiff/
for i in `*`; do diff /fileswithchanges/$i /fileswithoutchanges/$i >> mypatch.diff; done
```

However patch doesn't see this as valid input because there's no filename header included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`patchutils`](https://github.com/twaugh/patchutils) provides `filterdiff` that can do this:

```
diff -ur old/ new/ | filterdiff -I filelist > patchfile
```

It is packaged for [several linux distributions](https://repology.org/project/patchutils/versions)